# Convert second column in range from letter to number

Tags: excel, vba

I use the below `VBA` to extract the second column of a range:

```
Sub Extract_Column ()
Sheet1.Range("H4").Value = Split(Sheet1.Range("L28:AE30").Address, "$")(3)
End Sub
```

All this works fine.

However, now I want to convert the `column letter` to a `column number`. 
Therefore I tried to go with this VBA:

```
Sub Extract_Column_2 ()
Sheet1.Range("H4").Value = Split(Sheet1.Range("L28:AE30").Address, "$")(3).Column
End Sub
```

However, with this I get `runtime error 424`.

What do I need to change to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple ways really. If you want to use a method that can be used on any `Range` like: `Sheet1.Range("L28")`, try:

```
Sheet1.Range("H4").Value = Sheet1.Range("L28:AE30").Columns(Sheet1.Range("L28:AE30").Columns.Count).Column
```

Or written a little different:

```
Sheet1.Range("H4").Value = Sheet1.Range("L28:AE30").Columns.Count - 1 + Sheet1.Range("L28:AE30").Column
```

Or even using `Evaluate`:

```
Sheet1.Range("H4").Value = Evaluate("MAX(COLUMN(" & Sheet1.Range("L28:AE30").Address & "))")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next piece of code, please:

```
Sub testLongAndLetterFromAddress()
 Dim strL As String
   strL = Split(Sheet1.Range("L28:AE30").address, "$")(3)
   Debug.Print Columns(strL).Column
   Debug.Print Range(strL & 1).Column
   Debug.Print Cells(1, strL).Column
   'and in a single line:
   Debug.Print Columns(Split(Sheet1.Range("L28:AE30").address, "$")(3)).Column

   'different way:
   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = Range("L28:AE30")
   Debug.Print rng.Column + rng.Columns.count - 1
   Debug.Print rng.Offset(, rng.Columns.count - 1).Column
End Sub
```

There is no `Column` property for a string ("AE"). That's why the error...

It is a good habit to explicitly declare the range, using the specific sheet, but in such a case, `Range("L28:AE30")` will be enough, due to the fact that it would return the same address for any sheet... `ActiveSheet` in the short way.